# Solve the following recurrence relation: $f(N,d) = p*f(N-1,d-1) + (1-p)*f(N-1,d+1)$ subject to constraints in the body.

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, binomial-coefficients, recursion

The constraints are $f(0,0)=1, f(0,k)=0\space \forall k \neq 0, f(N,k)=0 \space \forall k>N\space0\leq p\leq 1$ .

When working on a probability problem, I came across this recursion when working with random walks. For symmetric random walks, with $p=\frac{1}{2}$, I found a closed form solution of $2^{-N}*$ ${N}\choose{\lfloor{\frac{k}{2}}\rfloor} $. To do so, I wrote out the first few terms, noticed a pattern, then used induction. I cannot find a nice pattern writing out the first few terms of the general form with $p$.

My gut instinct is that I will get something with binomial coefficients, since this recurrence relation looks an awful lot like the recurrence relation for binomial coefficients, and the solution for $p=\frac{1}{2}$ has binomial coefficients. Does anyone have any insights or suggestions?

I also will add, I tried turning this into a PDE and I tried some generating function approaches, but the initial/boundary conditions have given me difficulty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(n,d)$ is the probability that, when you repeat $n$ independent events that have a probability of success of $p$, and a probability of failure of $1-p$, that the number of successes minus the number of failures is $d$.

Let $s$ be the number of successes and $f$ be the number of failures. Since $s+f=n$ and $s-f=d$, it follows that $s=(n+d)/2$. Therefore, we need $(n+d)/2$ successes out of $n$ independent events with probability $p$. This is answered by a binomial distribution. Therefore,
$$
f(n,d)=\binom{n}{(n+d)/2}p^{(n+d)/2}(1-p)^{(n-d)/2}\;.
$$

However, there is an exception. If $n$ and $d$ have opposite parities, then it is impossible for the difference between the number of successes and failures to be $d$. In this case, $f(n,d)=0$.

Comment: If d and n are opposite parity, how are you defining (n+d)/2?

Comment: @PatrickGambill see edit

Comment: I think this is correct. I realize I didn't state the constraints properly, and this is a different question than the one I originally intended to ask. Thank you for your insight.

Comment: @PatrickGambill Feel free to edit the question with the correct boundary conditions, and I will do my best to answer. Or, you can post another question, and I will answer that one.

Comment: Thank you! The constraint at 0 is the big change.